# ssh sudo command to local machine

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have two machines master, slave. They have passwordless ssh setup between them. i.e
master -> master and master -> slave

I noticed the following problem

```
user@master$ ssh master sudo whoami
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
user@master$ ssh slave sudo whoami
root
user@master$ ssh -t master sudo whoami
[sudo] password for user:
```

I am suprprised i have to type password for local machine but not for remote! 
How can i bypass the sudo prompt on master itself?

Thanks

Comment: What user are you logging in as on slave, and what OS is it using? Also, paste the contents of your .ssh/config file - make sure to change the IPs though :)

Comment: by default ssh takes the current user, which above case is "user" ..both machines have same user names. I am using ubuntu oneiric on master and natty on slave.

Comment: In which case you should move this question to askubuntu.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Add your user entry to `/etc/sudoers`, by using `visudo` tool.

Line should look like:

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This would allow you to bypass password prompt.